# Assigning same function to every button and changing the function parameter when any button is clicked.

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" id="number"/>
<input type="button" value="create button" onclick="createbtn()"/> 
<div class="buttons"></div>

<script>
function createbtn() 
{
 var buttons_container = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")[0];
 var n=document.getElementById("number").value;

 buttons_container.innerHTML = '';

 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "button");
  x.setAttribute("value", i);
  x.setAttribute("id","x"+i);
  buttons_container.appendChild(x);
  x.addEventListener('click',(function(i_local_copy){return function()
  {rotate(i_local_copy);};})(i));
 } 

}

 function rotate(p)
 {  
  var n=document.getElementById("number").value;
  var j=n;
  var k=0; 
  for(i=n;i>p;i--)
  {
   document.getElementById("x"+i).value=i-p;
  }
  for(i=1;i<=p;i++)
  {
   document.getElementById("x"+i).value=(j-(p-1))+k; 
   k++;
  }
 }
</script>
```

The above code is to create the number of buttons equal to the number entered in text-field and each button is assigned an event so that when a button is clicked serially the button values gets rotated.I want to assign same function to every button(eg. rotate(i) where every button must have common i value )and the value of i in rotate function must increment when any of the button is clicked.

Comment: That could would appear to do that. What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is whether it's possible to do this:

```
x.addEventListener('click',(function(i_local_copy){return function()
  {rotate(i_local_copy);};})(i));
```

...more simply, the answer is yes, with `Function#bind` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.bind) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)):

```
x.addEventListener('click', rotate.bind(null, i));
```

`Function#bind` returns a new function (a "bound" function) that, when called will call the original function with a given `this` value (the first argument) followed by any arguments you give `bind`, followed by any arguments the bound function was called with.

Sinc eyou're not using `this` in your `rotate`, it doesn't matter what we give for the first argument to `bind`. We pass `i` as the second argument to `bind`, so that's what `rotate` will see as its first argument when the bound function is called.

---

In a comment you've said you want all of the buttons to share the same variable. If so, just declare it at the same level as you declare `rotate`. `rotate` will then close over it.

Here's a much simpler example to demonstrate the idea:

```js
// An inline-invoked scoping function to avoid creating blobals
(function() {
  // The variable they all share
  var counter = 0;
  
  // Hook up the buttons
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      // Increment the shared variable
      ++counter;
      
      // Show it and the button that incremented it
      console.log(this.value + " clicked, counter = " + counter);
    }, false);
  });
})();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" value="Button 2">
<input type="button" value="Button 3">
```

Comment: Thank you!! it is working well,but I wanna assign every button with same i value and increment it when any of the button is clicked.Is it possible?can you help me with this?

Comment: @sagar: You mean you want them all to share a variable?

Comment: Yes! is it possible?

Comment: @sagar: Yes, just declare it at the same level as `rotate`. `rotate` will close over it, and so all calls to `rotate` will use the same variable. (In the example in the question, that means you'd be declaring the variable globally. But there's no need for that, if it were me I'd wrap *all* of your code in a self-invoking scoping function to avoid creating globals.)